# How to put DATEDIF and IFISBLANK together?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 3 total cells I'm working with. One houses today's date (A1), the second has the date the request was made (B1) and the third has the date of the event (C1). My team had previously used DATEDIF to calculate, in days, how many days are in between B1 and A1 to populate in D1 which left a huge mess since there is sometimes a number in C1 which is where the IF(ISBLANK) comes in.

My main goal is to calculate the days between A1 and C1, but C1 can be left blank at which point B1 can be used instead. I want to add this all into one formula to populate in one cell so we can get the days in between A1 and C1 or A1 and B1 if the C1 field is empty. It would also be amazing if there was a way to get rid of the A1 column and just include "today" in the formula so it will automatically calculate the date. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the A1=Today?

Answer (score 2):

Like this maybe?

[image]

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),DATEDIF(TODAY(),B1,"D"),DATEDIF(TODAY(),C1,"D"))
```

In words: If C1 is empty, calculate the difference between B1 and today, otherwise, calculate the difference between C1 and today.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I was just about to post exactly the same solution, but you beat me to it!